# Read without removing message from JMS queue

Tags: java, spring, message-queue, spring-jms

How to read a message from WebSphere MQ without deleting the original message from queue?

I have spring application which reads the message from the WebSphere MQ.
After reading, I have a process method which will process the data retrieved from queue.

Step 1:

```
response = jmsTemplate.receive();
//Message automatically removed from queue.
```

Step 2:

```
process(response);
```

There are chances of throwing exceptions in process method. In case of exceptions, I need to retain the message in the queue.

Is it possible? Is their any way to delete the message only on user acknowledgement?

I tried adding the following:

```
jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

...but still the message is getting deleted.

`JmsTemplate` creating code snippet:

```
JndiConnectionFactorySupport connectionFactoryBean = new JndiConnectionFactorySupport();
    connectionFactoryBean.setBindingsDir(this.bindingDir);


        connectionFactoryBean
                .setConnectionFactoryName(connectionFactoryName);
        connectionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactoryBean.getObject());


    JndiDestinationResolver destinationResolver = new JndiDestinationResolver();
    destinationResolver.setJndiTemplate(connectionFactoryBean
            .getJndiTemplate());

    jmsTemplate.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver);
    jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(20000);
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(this.defaultDestinationName);
```

Tried the `jmsTemplate.execute()` method as below:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "unchecked" })
        Message responseMessage = (Message) jmsTemplate.execute(
            new SessionCallback() { 
                public Object doInJms(Session session)
                        throws JMSException {
                    MessageConsumer consumer = session
                    .createConsumer(jmsTemplate.getDestinationResolver().resolveDestinationName(session, "QUEUE_NAME", false));
                    Message response = consumer.receive(1);
                    try {
                        testMethod();//this method will throw exception.
                        response.acknowledge();
                        consumer.close();
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        consumer.close();//control will come here.
                    }
                    
                    return response;
                }
        }, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with `receive()` methods because the operation is complete (from the session perspective) when the receive method returns.

You need to run the code that might fail within the scope of the session; e.g. with a `JmsTemplate.execute()` with a `SessionCallback` - something like this...

```
this.jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("foo", "bar");
try {
    String value = this.jmsTemplate.execute(session -> {
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(
                this.jmsTemplate.getDestinationResolver().resolveDestinationName(session, "foo", false));
        String result;
        try {
            Message received = consumer.receive(5000);
            result = (String) this.jmsTemplate.getMessageConverter().fromMessage(received);
            // Do some stuff that might throw an exception
            received.acknowledge();
        }
        finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
        return result;
    }, true);
    System.out.println(value);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Tried the execute() method. (Code snippet added in question). It works!!! Thanks a lot Gary Russell..!!!

Answer (score 3):

You have to **browse** the queue.

Example of real code that was executed making usage of Websphere MQ

> ```
> public void browseMessagesAndJiraCreation(String jiraUserName, String jiraPassword) {
>
>     int counterMessages = jmsTemplate.browse(destinationQueueName, new BrowserCallback<Integer>() {
>
>         @Override
>         public Integer doInJms(final Session session, final QueueBrowser queueBrowser) throws JMSException {
>             Enumeration<TextMessage> enumeration = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
>             int counterMessages = 0;
>             while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
>                 counterMessages += 1;
>                 TextMessage msg = enumeration.nextElement();
>                 logger.info("Found : {}", msg.getText());
>                 JiraId jiraId = jiraManager.createIssue(jiraUserName, jiraPassword);
>                 jiraManager.attachFileToJira(jiraId, msg.getText(), jiraUserName, jiraPassword);
>             }
>             return counterMessages;
>         }
>     });
>     logger.info("{}:messages were browsed and processed from queue:{}.", counterMessages, destinationQueueName);
> }
> ```

Explanations:

- usage of the Spring Framework JmsTemplate
- you pass the String gestinationQueueName (example destinationQueueName=QL.PREFCNTR.USER.REPLY)
- Java enumeration of Text messages
- counterMessages is the counter of messages that were processed
- messages are NOT consumed!

Answer (score 1):

You can add transactional processing of JMS messages. See [the example](http://xpadro.blogspot.com.by/2013/08/spring-jms-processing-messages-within.html)

Your listener should be `"transacted"`. Like this

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="transacted">
    <jms:listener ref="notificationProcessor" destination="incoming.queue"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

Comment: i am not using the JMS configuration xml. Instead the JmsTemplate object is created using java.  (Code snippet added in question)